# TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len() selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

first of all i'm sorry if this isn't the good place to ask my question i'm trying to learn python
i'm learning web form filling automation
here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
print(df.iloc[1])

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://my.web.site')

for i in df.index:
    entry = df.iloc[i]
    print(entry["CN"])
    print(entry["NIN"])
    CarteNational = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div/input')
    CarteNational.send_keys(entry["CN"])
    NumeroIdentification = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[5]/div/div/input')
    NumeroIdentification.send_keys(entry["NIN"])
```

here is output error

```
C:\Users\Jean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe "D:/Users/Jean/Desktop/New folder (2)/pp.py"
CN           108852200
NIN    109970984300004
Name: 1, dtype: int64
108853300
109971114300004
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Jean\Desktop\New folder (2)\pp.py", line 16, in <module>
    CarteNational.send_keys(entry["CN"])
  File "C:\Users\Jean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 541, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "C:\Users\Jean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 148, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what am I missing? browser opens but doesn't fill

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in len(df.index):
```

This should do the trick!